# UWP C# SQL Server Connection local network 'Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, networking, uwp

Using UWP C# trying to connect to a server on the same network I keep getting an error:

> System.Exception: 'Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL
> Server Browser has been started.'
>
> Inner Exception
>  SocketException: An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host

Trouble Shooting Steps

- I've Made sure that the TCP in enabled
- Created a port rule 1433
- I've made sure that SQl server browser is running on the server
- Tried connection string with both IP and Computer Name

the string I'm using is:

```
@"Data Source=.\SERVER-DEV\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=**********;User ID=Reece;Password=**********;";
```

It connects to the database I just don't understand why it's then giving this error,

I'm using the System.Data.SqlClient;
the error is flagged on `conn.open();`.

```
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = exacutionString;
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The SQL Browser service operates on UDP port 1434. When you specify an instance name in your connection string the client process uses the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to pass the instance name to the SQL Browser service, which maps the instance name to the TCP port on which the instance is listening, and passes that port number back to the client. The client then attempts a connection on that TCP port number to utilize the SQL services. If you already know the port the instance is listening on then use `Server=YourServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber;` in the connection string to bypass it.

Comment: A database has separate credentials from the connection.  Best way of debugging is to use SSMS and test connection as well as performing a query to database.  A database has two method for credentials 1) Windows Credentials 2) SQL credentials (username and password). Once you open the Server with SSMS you can check the credentials to determine what type of credentials you need to access a database.  A server may have more than one database.

Comment: We have document about  [Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases), please check it and confirm if has enabled  Enterprise Authentication  capability and   Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client), and Private Networks (Client & Server).